# What languages could David Livingstone speak?

Tags: language, christianity, africa, exploration

What languages could [David Livingstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Livingstone) speak? I am certain that he spoke English and Setswana, but presumably neither of these would have been any use for the last seven years of his life. I have looked at several lives of Livingstone but haven't found an answer yet.

Comment: He had tuition in Greek, Latin, Hebrew; he studied Dutch.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks. Do you have a reference for the Dutch? I was really thinking of the African language(s) he must have learned when he was in what are now Zaire and Tanzania.

Comment: @user558840 - "Livingstone left London on 8 December 1840, passenger on a sailing brig bound for the Cape of Good Hope, along with two other LMS missionaries: Ross, who had been ordained at the same service as him, and Ross's wife. During the long voyage he studied Dutch and Tswana language, and the captain gave him extensive tuition in navigation." (Wikipedia)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey do note that tuition in ancient languages was (and still is today) primarily focused on reading ancient works rather than having practical conversations in the language. Studying Biblical Hebrew won't help you a great deal with ordering a coffee in Tel Aviv.